# Database error after moving host and renaming the DB

Tags: 7, drush, configuration

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>       '<olddb>.semaphore' doesn't exist: `SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = 
>       :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init )` in `lock_may_be_available()` (line 167 of 
>       /<somedir>/includes/lock.inc).

When I load the site it tried to load semaphore info from the old DB.

I moved the site to a new host and renamed the database. Change the settings file. It has the right user, password, host, dbname etc.

I have cleared the cache. Running drush says that all is good. It can connect and bootstrap Drupal.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I assume semaphore is in the database DB as other tables? You didn't configure the old/new server for shared databases? Table prefixing is off?

Comment: yes, all tables are there. There is no table prefixing. Drush can bootstrap Drupal, so there is a proper connection to the new database. The error message comes in the shutdown process. Renaming the database to the old name, and everything works again.